# Parse error: syntax error wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in ../public_html/wp-content/themes/nano/includes/galleri.php on line 64**

Please help me to get my code work!

http://pastebin.com/B0ndywWc

The code in question:

```
<?php
    $ccfit_img_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() ), 'ccfit_thumb', false );
    $ccfit_img_big = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() ), 'ccfit_big', false );

    echo '
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="inner">
        <a href="'. $ccfit_img_big[0] .'"></a>
        <img src="'. $ccfit_img_thumb[0] .'">
        <h2>'. get_the_title() .'</h2>
        <p>'. get_the_content() .'</p>
        <hr>
        <?php
          if (isset($featuredImages) && is_array($featuredImages)) {
            foreach($featuredImages as $images) {
                $thumb = $images['thumb']; // <---- line 64
                $fullImage = $images['full'];
                print ' <a class="fancybox" href="'. $fullImage .'" style="text-align:center">&laquo; Take a look &raquo;</a> ';
            }
        }
        ?>
        </div></div>';
?>
```

Comment: The link is not working. Can you post the code here ?

Comment: Why are you ending your lines with a comma? PHP lines should end with a semicolon

Comment: I've try with ";" and "," nothing work @jcsanyi

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax errors or a code fixing request.

Comment: Like a said!! - It's dosen't work with "," OR ";" !!!

Comment: This is more than just a syntax error. It's a misunderstanding around embedding `<?php` tags inside a string being echoed.

Comment: @jcsanyi - look at this code. http://pastebin.com/FutJmRGZ. The echo ' <a class="fancybox" ..... ' line dosen't print out..

Answer (score 5):

The error is actually at line 53:

```
echo '
```

You never close that quote... or at least, you're trying to nest PHP tags inside an echo statement.

What's actually happening at line 64 is that the first quote in `'thumb'` is being interpreted as the end-quote for the echo - resulting in `thumb` being the unexpected string.

The inner `<?php` tags is not interpreted - it's just treated as part of the string being echoed out.

Pay attention to the syntax highlighting in the code I edited into your question above, and it might be a bit clearer what's happening.

Comment: This answer was brought to you by plain old syntax highlighting. +1

Comment: Sorry, but I am a beginner in wordpress / php and I'm trying really ..

Answer (score 2):

```
    $thumb = $images['thumb'], <------------------- line 64
    $fullImage = $images['full'],
```

should be

```
    $thumb = $images['thumb'];
    $fullImage = $images['full'];
```

Comment: I've try... dosen't work.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in ../public_html/wp-content/themes/nano/includes/galleri.php on line 64 - @jcsanyi